# XML Schema send empty tags with closing tags and default values root names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, dapper

I have the following xml I wish to reproduce but so far i have managed the following to get the following but it should print out the empty elements as well as a root element the below is a few examples of what i have so far.

I am using dapper for my data access and linq for management of my collections and a helper class for my xml serialisation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfFieldSchemaXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>LineID</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>OrderID</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>OrderNumber</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>StockItemID</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>ItemType</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>ItemCode</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>ItemDesc</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>DepotCode</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>Text</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>CostPrice</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>4</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>UnitOfSale</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>Price</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>4</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>LineTotal</Name>
    <Precision>19</Precision>
    <Scale>4</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>NominalCode</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>NominalCC</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>NominalDept</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>VatCode</Name>
    <Precision>10</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>VatCode</Name>
    <Precision>10</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>VatRate</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>
  <FieldSchemaXml>
    <Name>VatRate</Name>
    <Precision>0</Precision>
    <Scale>0</Scale>
  </FieldSchemaXml>

</ArrayOfFieldSchemaXml>
```

Correct Layout what mine above should look like below What it should look like through my program. This is tooling im creating to save me time in creating this xml through a third party program I am automating this to cut my time down.

```
<PersistentObject Name="SopOrderss">
      <TableName />
      <Description />
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="CustomerID">
          <DbType>Int64</DbType>
          <Precision>11</Precision>
          <Scale>0</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>0</FormatScale>
          <FormatMask>99999999999</FormatMask>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Customer ID</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TestDate">
          <DbType>Date</DbType>
          <Precision>3</Precision>
          <Scale>0</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>0</FormatScale>
          <FormatMask>99/99/9999</FormatMask>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>test</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TestString">
          <DbType>String</DbType>
          <Precision>64</Precision>
          <Scale>2</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>2</FormatScale>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Test String</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TestMoney">
          <UserDataType>MonetaryValue2dp</UserDataType>
          <DbType>String</DbType>
          <Precision>12</Precision>
          <Scale>2</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>2</FormatScale>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Test Money</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TestDecimal">
          <DbType>Decimal</DbType>
          <Precision>18</Precision>
          <Scale>0</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>0</FormatScale>
          <FormatMask>999999999999999999.</FormatMask>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Test Decimal</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TestCurrency">
          <DbType>Currency</DbType>
          <Precision>11</Precision>
          <Scale>2</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>2</FormatScale>
          <FormatMask>99999999999.99</FormatMask>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Test Currency</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Test">
          <DbType>String</DbType>
          <Precision>64</Precision>
          <Scale>2</Scale>
          <FillType>None</FillType>
          <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
          <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
          <AllowOverwrite>True</AllowOverwrite>
          <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
          <IsDeltaField>false</IsDeltaField>
          <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
          <IsTransient>false</IsTransient>
          <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
          <OverrideFormatting>false</OverrideFormatting>
          <IsLockable>false</IsLockable>
          <Direction>Input</Direction>
          <ValueSetByDatabase>false</ValueSetByDatabase>
          <FormatScale>2</FormatScale>
          <NegativeFormatting>Standard</NegativeFormatting>
          <Group>false</Group>
          <AggregateFunction>None</AggregateFunction>
          <IsExcludedFromCopy>false</IsExcludedFromCopy>
          <IsExpression>false</IsExpression>
          <FriendlyName>Test</FriendlyName>
          <IsBrowsable>true</IsBrowsable>
          <IsQueryable>true</IsQueryable>
          <IsEnumeration>false</IsEnumeration>
          <IsAddInPrimaryKey>false</IsAddInPrimaryKey>
          <AddInTableName />
          <AddInRelationField />
          <IsMember>false</IsMember>
          <IsExcludedFromReset>false</IsExcludedFromReset>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <IsCacheable>false</IsCacheable>
      <AllowZeroKeys>false</AllowZeroKeys>
      <AlwaysAllowPaging>false</AlwaysAllowPaging>
      <Namespace />
      <PagingFields />
      <TransactionMode>Required</TransactionMode>
      <IsStoredProcedure>false</IsStoredProcedure>
      <ProcedureReturnType />
    </PersistentObject>
```

The following is my model at present.

```
public class FieldSchemaXml
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DBType { get; set; }
    public string Precision { get; set; }
    public string Scale { get; set; }
    public string FillType { get; set; }
    public string IsNullable { get; set; }
    public string IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public string AllowOverwrite { get; set; }
    public string IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }

    public string IsDeltaField { get; set; }
    public string IsIndexed { get; set; }
    public string IsTransient { get; set; }
    public string IsUnique { get; set; }

    public string OverrideFormatting { get; set; }
    public string IsLockable { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string ValueSetByDatabase { get; set; }
    public string FormatScale { get; set; }
    public string FormatMask { get; set; }
    public string NegativeFormatting { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string AggregateFunction { get; set; }
    public string IsExcludedFromCopy { get; set; }
    public string IsExpression { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string IsBrowsable { get; set; }
    public string IsQueryable { get; set; }
    public string IsEnumeration { get; set; }

    public string IsAddInPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public string AddInTableName { get; set; }
    public string AddInRelationField { get; set; }
    public string IsMember { get; set; }
    public string IsExcludedFromReset { get; set; }
}
```

The Following is my seriizer so as you can see I need the empty items to still be produced and is there a way i can give default values for example if the value of 
false is empty in this list how do i set it to be false and still output ?.

```
public  static class HelperXml
{
    public static T FromXML<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }

    public static  string ToXML<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code under my generate button which is calling the above toxml method

```
 private void genXmlSchema_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        List<TableDefnition> _newList= db.GetALLTableDeiniations();
        List<FieldSchemaXml> _newSchemaList = new List<FieldSchemaXml>();

        foreach(var item in _newList)
        {
            FieldSchemaXml _newSchema = new FieldSchemaXml();
            _newSchema.Name = item.Field;
            _newSchema.Precision = item.Precision.ToString();
            _newSchema.Scale = item.Scale.ToString();
            _newSchemaList.Add(_newSchema);
        }

        schemeContent.Text = HelperXml.ToXML(_newSchemaList);
 }
```

Questions.

1. How do I add the root node PersistentObject and TableName and description my schema in same fashion as the example layout i want to mimic as I provided.

**Edit 2**
When I attempt it as the person below suggested I am getting a object not set error when i run it no error during compile just at runtime this is how im trying to pass my object into the list.

```
private void genXmlSchema_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _tableName = "";

    PersistentObject _newObject = new PersistentObject();
    List<FieldSchemaXml> _newFieldList = new List<FieldSchemaXml>();

    foreach (var item in _newList)
    {
        _newObject.TableName = "MCSGROUP";
        _newObject.Name = "mcsgroup";
        FieldSchemaXml _newSchema = new FieldSchemaXml();

        _newSchema.Precision = item.Precision.ToString();
       _newSchema.Scale = Convert.ToString(item.Scale);
        _newSchema.Name = item.Field;
        _newSchema.IsUnique = "false";
        _newSchema.IsReadOnly = "false";
        _newSchema.IsQueryable = "true";
        if(item.is_nullable ==1)
        {
            _newSchema.IsNullable = "true";
        }else
            _newSchema.IsNullable = "false";

        _newSchema.IsReadOnly = "false";
        _newSchema.IsUnique = "false";
        _newSchema.Group = "false";
        _newObject.TableName = "MCSGroupTest";
        _newObject.Name = "test";
        _newSchema.IsLockable = "false";
        _newSchema.IsDeltaField = "false";
        _newSchema.IsPrimaryKey = "false";
        _newSchema.FillType= "None";
        _newSchema.Direction = "Input";

        _newObject.Fields.Add(_newSchema);
    }            
    schemeContent.Text = HelperXml.ToXML(_newObject);
}
```

My new definiation in acordance ot the answer below.

```
 public class SageXmlDefiniation
 {
    public class PersistentObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Fields")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
        public List<FieldSchemaXml> Fields { get; set; }

    }
    public class FieldSchemaXml
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DBType { get; set; }
        public string Precision { get; set; }
        public string Scale { get; set; }
        public string FillType { get; set; }
        public string IsNullable { get; set; }
        public string IsReadOnly { get; set; }
        public string AllowOverwrite { get; set; }
        public string IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }

        public string IsDeltaField { get; set; }
        public string IsIndexed { get; set; }
        public string IsTransient { get; set; }
        public string IsUnique { get; set; }

        public string OverrideFormatting { get; set; }
        public string IsLockable { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string ValueSetByDatabase { get; set; }
        public string FormatScale { get; set; }
        public string FormatMask { get; set; }
        public string NegativeFormatting { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string AggregateFunction { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromCopy { get; set; }
        public string IsExpression { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public string IsBrowsable { get; set; }
        public string IsQueryable { get; set; }
        public string IsEnumeration { get; set; }

        public string IsAddInPrimaryKey { get; set; }
        public string AddInTableName { get; set; }
        public string AddInRelationField { get; set; }
        public string IsMember { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromReset { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *When I attempt it as the person below suggested I am getting a object not set error when i run it* Please see [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3744182).

Comment: Your original code had following :  List<TableDefnition> _newList= db.GetALLTableDeiniations();  In Edit 2 I do not see the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Use following classes :

```
    public class PersistentObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Fields")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Field")]
        List<FieldSchemaXml> Fields { get; set; }
    }
    public class FieldSchemaXml
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DBType { get; set; }
        public string Precision { get; set; }
        public string Scale { get; set; }
        public string FillType { get; set; }
        public string IsNullable { get; set; }
        public string IsReadOnly { get; set; }
        public string AllowOverwrite { get; set; }
        public string IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }

        public string IsDeltaField { get; set; }
        public string IsIndexed { get; set; }
        public string IsTransient { get; set; }
        public string IsUnique { get; set; }

        public string OverrideFormatting { get; set; }
        public string IsLockable { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public string ValueSetByDatabase { get; set; }
        public string FormatScale { get; set; }
        public string FormatMask { get; set; }
        public string NegativeFormatting { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string AggregateFunction { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromCopy { get; set; }
        public string IsExpression { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public string IsBrowsable { get; set; }
        public string IsQueryable { get; set; }
        public string IsEnumeration { get; set; }

        public string IsAddInPrimaryKey { get; set; }
        public string AddInTableName { get; set; }
        public string AddInRelationField { get; set; }
        public string IsMember { get; set; }
        public string IsExcludedFromReset { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Hi How do i assign the fields of the persitant object thanks.

Comment: Hi please see edit 2 above im getting an error when trying to assign to the fields object.